# Popup in BlackBerry 10

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry-10, cascade

How do I show a popup in Blackberry 10? I want to show popup when any contact is added /deleted/updated.  I took one method like this---

```
void ContactEditor::showToast(QString text) {
bb::system::SystemToast toast;
toast.setBody(text);
toast.setPosition(bb::system::SystemUiPosition::MiddleCenter);
toast.exec();
}
```

and called like this---

```
showToast("contact added...");
```

included file for System Toast also.

but this is giving me error----

```
make[2]: *** [o-g/addressbook] Error 1
make[1]: *** [debug] Error 2
make: *** [Simulator-Debug] Error 2
```

can somebody tell me whats the problem ?

Comment: This isn't the actual error, error is higher up. Did you include SystemToast?

Comment: yeah. I have included that also.

Comment: Please provide a self-contained code and the compiler options how you build so that we can reproduce the error.

Answer (score 4):

Add `LIBS += -lbbsystem` to your application pro file. and include

`#include <bb/system/SystemToast>`

```
         SystemToast *toast = new SystemToast(this);
                                toast->setBody("Your Toast");
                                toast->setPosition(SystemUiPosition::MiddleCenter);
                                toast->show();
```